# Can't figure out "IndexError: list index out of range" problem in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, index-error

So, I'm trying to remove all numbers in array bigger than P (maximum) and can't figure out what's the problem with the code.

The code:

```
from array import array

A = array("i")
n = int(input("Number of elements: "))
A = [0] * n

print("Type elements of array: ")
for i in range(n):
    A[i] = int(input())

P = int(input("Max: "))

for i in range(n):
    if A[i] > P:
        A.pop(i)

print(A)
```

The result:

```
if A[i] > P:
   ~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Well, if you pop an element off the array, the array gets shorter. So when you get to what used to be the end of the array, it's not there anymore. You need a `while` loop that tests the length of `A` each time. Also the way you're doing it now will result in not testing the element after any that was popped. To fix that you need a `while` instead of your `if`.

Comment: Understanding your example could be improved if you would remove the `input()` parts and replace it with example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to remove values from the list it's probably easier just to reconstruct it using a list comprehension and appropriate conditional check. Something like this:

```
from array import array

n = int(input('Number of elements: '))

a = []

for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input(f'Element {i+1}: ')))

m = int(input('Max: '))

a = array('I', [e for e in a if e < m])

print(a)
```

**Console (example):**

```
Number of elements: 5
Element 1: 10
Element 2: 20
Element 3: 30
Element 4: 40
Element 5: 50
Max: 35
array('I', [10, 20, 30])
```

Comment: can i do like this with array? cuz the task required an array

Comment: @hsl Why do you need an array when a list will suffice?

Comment: for the school. task says you'll need an array

Comment: @hsl "school" probably doesn't know what the implications are of using an array. People with little Python knowledge frequently use the terms *array* and *list* synonymously - but that is incorrect. If you **must** use an array then school would need to tell you about the data type to be stored in it. This is one of the key differences. Elements of Python lists can be of any type even within the same list.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to explain you the core of your problem. Look at this piece of your code please:

```
for i in range(n):
    if A[i] > P:
        A.pop(i)
```

First you need to improve the `for` loop

```
for idx, val in enumerate(A):
    # ...
```

Second you need to understand that you remove items from a list while you iterate over it. That cause problems. So do every iterate over a copy of that list. In that example the `[:]` does the copy.

```
for idx, val in enumerate(A[:]):
    if val > P:
        A.pop(idx)
```

## Alternative approach

You can use a filter with an inverted condition.

```
new_a = list(filter(lambda val: val <= P, A))
```

The `lambda val: val <= P` is a nameless function called on each element in the list `A`. If the condition is `True` that element will be a part of the resulting new list.

But the result of `filter()` is not a list but an [iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator). You can convert that iterator into a `list` via `list()`.